# How to load item/classes in library to a dictionary?

Tags: actionscript-3, dictionary

Without creating a list for the name of the items in the library, isit possible to auto get the name of the item and load it into a dictionary?

Currently what I'm doing is, 1st loading the swf using DataLoader from greensock

```
var contentLoader:DataLoader = new DataLoader('s_res.swf', {onComplete:completeHandler, format:'binary' } )
```

Then after I get the content, I use swfclassexplorer from [flassari](http://flassari.is/2008/07/swf-class-explorer-for-as3/)

to pass in the binary data I got

```
private static var list:Array;

    public function setup($byeArray:ByteArray):void
    {
        ba = $byeArray;
        var _loader:Loader = new Loader();
        var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
        _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        _loader.loadBytes(ba, loaderContext);
    }

    private function completeHandler($e:Event):void
    {list = SwfClassExplorer.getClassNames(ba);}
```

From here I can get a list of the name which I can get the file using Loadermax as well

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            var _class:Class = (LoaderMax.getLoader("mcA").getClass(list[i])) as Class;
        }
```

From here it all looks fine but I feel that this might not be the most direct to do since it has to go through another loader to get the name of the file, and then loop the list to add the items in 1 by 1

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the given link to swfclassexplorer, you should be able to switch to the SWF's context and call `flash.utils.getDefinitionByName()` against each of the listed classes. The result of each call will be a `Class` object which you then stuff into your dictionary. Also you can get rid of all the frameworks if you dig a bit into `flash.display.Loader` class and application domain context.

```
private var list:Vector.<String>;
private var dict:Dictionary=new Dictionary(); // here you want classes
var loader:Loader=new Loader();
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("s_res.swf");
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,setup);
loader.load(url, loaderContext);

function setup(e:Event):void {
    var loader:Loader=e.target as Loader;
    var ad:ApplicationDomain=loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain;
    list=ad.getQualifiedDefinitionNames();
    // here you get all class definitions
    for each (var s:String in list) dict[s]=flash.utils.getDefinitionByName(s); 
    // fill the dictionary
}
```

Maybe there are more humps, but this actually should do.

Answer (score 0):

apparently using swfloader from greensock this will work.

```
var ad:ApplicationDomain = $swfLoader.rawContent.loaderInfo.applicationDomain;
        list = ad.getQualifiedDefinitionNames();
```

Comment: Yes, if you need just the names, it should work, but instantiating classes might be inaccessible if there's a security issue between loaded SWF's `applicationDomain` and current domain.

Comment: hm, didn't think of that. For a more future-proof solutions I think your answer should be the way to go. Thanks!